# Is it correct to define nilpotent functions as equivalence classes?

Tags: differential-geometry, infinitesimals

I read in Giordano's paper on Infinitesimal Differential Geometry (http://www.iam.fmph.uniba.sk/amuc/_vol-73/_no_2/_giordano/giordano.pdf , p. 3-5 ) that infinitesimal numbers can be considered as equivalence classes $[h]$ and they can be generated by function, for example, $h(t)=t$.

Next Giordano wrote that if $x(t)=y(t)+o(t)$ for $t$->$0$ then $[x]=[y]$ or $x=y$.

Question: is it correct to define nilpotent functions as equivalence classes as it is defined for real numbers via Cauchy sequences of rational numbers with equivalence classes?

Thanks.

Comment: He defines *infinitesimals* as equivalence classes, not functions.  Of course, functions on his ring can also be viewed as equivalence classes, but that's a secondary phenomenon.

Comment: There is a difference between "define functions as equivalence classes" and "define equivalence classes of functions".

Comment: @MikhailKatz As I understood, he defined "nilpotent functions" ($t$, $sin(t)$ etc) as equivalence classes. Is it true?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I mean "define functions as equivalence classes"

Comment: @MikhailKatz How is it possible that if $x(t)=sin(t)$ and $y(t)=t$ then $x=y$?

Comment: We are talking about equivalence classes here. For example, if you define the real numbers as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers, then it will turn out that the sequence (0,0,...)  represents the same real number as the sequence (1,1/2,1/3,...)
.

Comment: @MikhailKatz So, if we want to define functions as equivalence classes, we can do it as real numbers. And if $x(t)=sin(t)$ $y(t)=t$ for $t$->$0$ then $[x]=[y]$. Is it so?

Comment: You are confusing *functions* and *numbers* (more precisely, elements of the ring that he wants to define).  Just as distinct Cauchy sequences can define the same real number, so also different $f$'s can define the same element of his ring.  Specifically, $\sin t$ and $t$ will be equivalent because their difference is higher-order near the origin.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Ok. I understand now. $sin t$ and $t$ are the same element.

Comment: @MikhailKatz I read about little-oh and big O notations but I understood that I have gaps in knowledge. Why can't we conclude from $x(t)=y(t)+o(t)$ that $x$ is close to $y$?

Comment: That depends on what order nilpotent elements you want to obtain.  If you want higher-order nilpotents, you may need to ask for little-o of a higher power of $t$.   At any rate, this approach is supposed to be fairly elementary (by comparison with SDG, for example).

Comment: @MikhailKatz If I define $x(t)=y(t)+o(t)$ as $x$ is close to $y$ then what nilpotent elements will I obtain?

Comment: If anything tending to zero faster than $t$ is considered equivalent to zero, then $h(t)=t$ will define a nilpotent infinitesimal, since $t^2$ will be equivalent to zero and therefore belong to the equivalence class of 0 in his ring.